# Why CQL DWITHIN returns different result than PostGIS DWITHIN?

Tags: postgis, geoserver, cql-filter

I have 2 tables in PostGIS that I publish to geoserver. both have same SRS (2039).

When I do the following query in PostGIS , I get 69 results :

```
 SELECT a.gid,b.gid
 FROM Table_A a INNER JOIN Table_B b
 ON ST_DWithin(a.geom, b.geom,1);
```

But when I do the same in CQL , I get error that result contains more than 1000 features.

This is my CQL :

```
http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wms?
LAYERS=a,b&STYLES=&FORMAT=image/png&SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.1.1&
REQUEST=GetMap&EXCEPTIONS=application/vnd.ogc.se_inimage&
SRS=EPSG:2039&
BBOX=589042.42768447,4914010.3926913,609134.78143081,4928059.3431623&
WIDTH=512&HEIGHT=358&
CQL_FILTER=
DWITHIN(geom,collectGeometries(queryCollection('b','geom','INCLUDE'),1,meters);
EXCLUDE
```

The Exclude at the end is because I don't want to see layer b as result.

Any explanations on this ?

* UPDATE ***

Layer A and Layer B are published to Geoserver , The dimensions in the request I get by default when I use PREVIEW LAYER (Layer A are lines and B are polygons)

Comment: Why do you show coordinates and dimensions in one query (CQL) and not in the other (SQL)? Maybe you could provide more data on what you have in PostGIS. Also, maybe break the CQL into a few more readable lines of code.

Comment: I've updated my question.